# Issues injecting mocked class into the class I am testing

Tags: php, mocking, phpunit

I have a class which is instantiating another class:

```php
<?php

namespace myPoject\Controllers;

use OAuth2\Request;
use OAuth2\Response;
use myPoject\auth\OAuthServer;

abstract class BaseController
{
    // ... unnecessary parts of class skipped
    public static function checkAuth(string $scopeRequired): array
    {
        $server = OAuthServer::getServer();

        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $response = new Response();
        if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest($request, $response, $scopeRequired)) {
            $response->send();
            die();
        } else {
            return array('success' => true, 'message' => 'You are authorized to access this API');
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test this function, so I have a test class:

```php
<?php

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;
use myPoject\Controllers\BaseController;
use OAuth2\Server;
use OAuth2\Response;
use myPoject\auth\OAuthServer;
use myPoject\Exceptions\CertificateException;

class BaseControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    public $bc;


    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->bc = $this
            ->getMockBuilder('myPoject\Controllers\BaseController')
            ->getMockForAbstractClass();
    }

// .. skipped parts

    public function testBaseController_checkAuth()
    {
        //mocked server
        $OAuthServerStub = $this
            ->getMockBuilder(OAuthServer::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->disableOriginalClone()
            ->disableArgumentCloning()
            ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
            ->getMock();
        
        //mocked response
        $mockResponse = new Response(array(), 200, array('Content-Type' => 'application/json'));
        $stubServer = $this->getMockBuilder(Server::class)
        ->disableOriginalConstructor()
        ->disableOriginalClone()
        ->disableArgumentCloning()
        ->disallowMockingUnknownTypes()
        ->getMock();
        
        $OAuthServerStub
            ->method('getServer')
            ->willReturn($stubServer);
        $stubServer
            ->method('verifyResourceRequest')
            ->willReturn($mockResponse);

        $checkAuthResponse = self::callMethod($this->bc, 'checkAuth', ['scopeRequired' => '']);
        $this->assertEquals('You are authorized to access this API', $checkAuthResponse['message']);
    }
```

I can see that it fails, since it tries to load an undefined constant. All the examples I have found inject the mock by mocking it and setting it via the constructor, or a setter. This is the only method I have using this class in my class, so I would prefer not doing it that way.
I have considered whether the mock of the parent class (since it is abstract) is the issue, but I like to keep classes that should not be instantiated abstract.

PHPUnit 9.6.16
PHP     8.2.9

Answer (score 2):

As you've hidden the dependency:

```php
    $server = OAuthServer::getServer();
```

You have the problem to set (inject) the mock.

Likely you want to have the `checkAuth()` method within every controller but then it remains unclear why it is static (to me).

As you start to begin sensing, dependencies need to be injected, this is a precondition so that you can mock them.

Given you use a static function to create the default `OAuthServer`, you can for your testing purposes either use an optional parameter and only take the default if unset (`null`) or you use a static property and do the same.

While this can solve your issue immediately, using the static methods are likely the problem in the first place.

As you call `checkAuth()` statically, it has no `$this` and henceforth there is not much use of mocks at all (as those are object instances).

See the following examples w/o static methods:

```php
abstract class BaseController
{
    // ... unnecessary parts of class skipped

    protected function getOAuthServer(): OAuthServer
    {
        return OAuthServer::getServer();
    }

    public function checkAuth(string $scopeRequired): array
    {
        $server = $this->getOAuthServer();

        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $response = new Response();
        if (!$server->verifyResourceRequest($request, $response, $scopeRequired)) {
            $response->send();
            die();
        } else {
            return array('success' => true, 'message' => 'You are authorized to access this API');
        }
    }
}
```

If you compare with this example, every child class - including the mock - may override `getOAuthServer()` and therefore you would be able to replace the instance.

As the `$server` is used to call a single method on, you can make that single method also directly part of your base controllers protocol instead, which should be even easier for mocking as mocking the server then is not necessary any longer:

```php
abstract class BaseController
{
    // ... unnecessary parts of class skipped

    protected function verifyResourceRequest(Request $request, Response $response, string $scopeRequired): bool
    {
        $server = OAuthServer::getServer();

        return $server->verifyResourceRequest($request, $response, $scopeRequired);
    }

    public function checkAuth(string $scopeRequired): array
    {
        $this->getOAuthServer();

        $request = Request::createFromGlobals();
        $response = new Response();
        if (!$this->verifyResourceRequest($request, $response, $scopeRequired)) {
            $response->send();
            die();
        } else {
            return array('success' => true, 'message' => 'You are authorized to access this API');
        }
    }
}
```

The problem to inject the mock is likely not the only issue, but then it's when you go into testing, you find those places. Static method calls often introduce a burden as those are just functional and more blackbox style and as your code progresses, it will become more and more with replaceable objects and dependency injection.

Given the single method call on the `OAuthServer` wrapped in a static method with a bit set up for that call (`Request` and `Response`) and then mixed results `$response->send();` + `die();` vs. `return array()` it's perhaps worth that you continue to experiment until you've come to a much simpler code and protocol.

Comment: I think i made it static, thinking that is should belong to the class and not the object/class instance. Your comments regarding that make sense. Your comment about simplification makes sense too - I think I started in two different directions at the same time and found myself here. Right now I am writing extensive Unit tests to ensure that I don't break anything and actually have the functionality I think I have before I continue expanding the code.

Comment: Hmm, then it's perhaps also worth to consider to make the code fail-safe even before writing (all) tests b/c otherwise you first mock yourself to death and finally you don't have any more fun streamlining the code. Perhaps what could help you to achieve more fail-safe programming that automatically breaks on error is to replace `string $scopeRequired` with a [string backed Enum](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.enumerations.backed.php). This help you to keep the list of scopes in a central place and never pass a wrong one, similar for return types and actually returning (never `die()`).

Comment: I am looking at the core functions first - to avoid assumptions when I extend those features. My principle for legacy code is "you touch it, you test it" - to avoid breaking the functions.